# Method of a generic class doesn't see 'new' property of a child class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, properties

I have a generic tree node class `ObservableTreeNode<K,V>`, with a method that should go through all nodes of a tree and examine them. I have two more classes:

`ElementTreeNode : ObservableTreeNode<string, HierarchyElement>`, and
 `ElementTreeNodeVisual : ElementTreeNode`.

The generic class looks like this:

```
public class ObservableTreeNode<K, V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ObservableTreeNode<K, V>> Children { get; set; }

    public ObservableTreeNode()
    {
        this.Children = new ObservableCollection<ObservableTreeNode<K, V>>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindNodeInTree<T>(
            T rootNode, Func<T, bool> predicate, bool firstOnly = false
        ) where T : ObservableTreeNode<K, V>
    {
        var resultNodes = new List<T>();
        var nodeQueue = new Queue<T>();
        nodeQueue.Enqueue(rootNode);
        while (nodeQueue.Any())
        {
            T currentNode = nodeQueue.Dequeue();
            Debug.WriteLine("Current node key: {0}", currentNode.Key);
            if (predicate(currentNode))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Match!");
                resultNodes.Add(currentNode);
                if (firstOnly)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("-FindInContext");
                    return resultNodes;
                }
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("The current node has {0} children.", currentNode.Children.Count);
            foreach (T n in currentNode.Children)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Enqueue child...");
                nodeQueue.Enqueue(n);
            }
        }
        return resultNodes;
    }
}
```

In my `ElementTreeNodeVisual` class, I must hide the `Children` property with a new one, otherwise the 3rd party (Infragistics' `XamDataTree`) control in my WPF application wouldn't enumerate the child nodes. So my `ElementTreeNodeVisual` class looks like this:

```
public class ElementTreeNodeVisual : ElementTreeNode
{
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public new ObservableCollection<ElementTreeNodeVisual> Children 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ElementTreeNodeVisual(ElementTreeNode elementTreeNode)
    {
        this.Children = new ObservableCollection<ElementTreeNodeVisual>();
        this.Element = elementTreeNode.Element;
        this.Parent = elementTreeNode.Parent;
        foreach (ElementTreeNode child in elementTreeNode.Children)
        {
            this.Children.Add(new ElementTreeNodeVisual(child));
        }
    }
}
```

}

My problem is, when I try call the `ElementTreeNodeVisual.FindNodeInTree` method, the method seems to be seeing the `Children` property of the base class - which has no items.
This is how I call the method:

```
        Func<ElementTreeNodeVisual, bool> isExpandedFunc = delegate(ElementTreeNodeVisual node) { return node.IsExpanded; };
        foreach (ElementTreeNodeVisual node in _hierarchyNodeVisuals)
        {
            var expandedNodes = ElementTreeNodeVisual.FindNodeInTree<ElementTreeNodeVisual>(node, isExpandedFunc);
            foreach (ElementTreeNode expandedNode in expandedNodes)
            {
                expandedNodeIds.Add(expandedNode.Key);
            }
        }
```

If I set a watch on the `node` variable inside the foreach loop, it shows the new `Children` property, with several child nodes. The `Debug.WriteLine(...)` in the `FindNodeInTree` method however, says there are 0 children.

As an emergency solution, I've copy-pasted the `FindNodeInTree` method and changed the T parameter to `where T : ElementTreeNodeVisual`. It works like this, but in the end there shouldn't be any copy-pasted code in there...

What should I change (either in the generic class or the child class) to make the `FindNodeInTree` method see the new property, when it's called on the child class?

Comment: The new modifier does not hide a base method or property when it is accessed through a reference to the base class.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I know that, but I assume that when I'm calling the generic method explicitly as <ElementTreeNodeVisual>, then T will be ElementTreeNodeVisual inside the method. If that assumption is wrong, how would one solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It's a little strange method but it should work.
First, add a virtual property collection in your base class. For example:

```
public virtual ObservableCollection<ObservableTreeNode<K, V>> VirtualChildren { 
   get { return Children; }
}
```

In your searching method change **Children** to **VirtualChildren**:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindNodeInTree<T>(
            T rootNode, Func<T, bool> predicate, bool firstOnly = false
        ) where T : ObservableTreeNode<K, V>
    {
        var resultNodes = new List<T>();
        var nodeQueue = new Queue<T>();
        nodeQueue.Enqueue(rootNode);
        while (nodeQueue.Any())
        {
            T currentNode = nodeQueue.Dequeue();
            Debug.WriteLine("Current node key: {0}", currentNode.Key);
            if (predicate(currentNode))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Match!");
                resultNodes.Add(currentNode);
                if (firstOnly)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("-FindInContext");
                    return resultNodes;
                }
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("The current node has {0} children.", currentNode.VirtualChildren.Count);
            foreach (T n in currentNode.VirtualChildren)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Enqueue child...");
                nodeQueue.Enqueue(n);
            }
        }
        return resultNodes;
    }
```

And override **VirtualChildren** property in **ElementTreeNodeVisual**:

```
    public override ObservableCollection<ObservableTreeNode<string, HierarchyElement>> VirtualChildren
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<ObservableTreeNode<string, HierarchyElement>>(Children); }
    }
```

Of course, returning new collection in property each time isn't very good. So you may replace this property by the virtual method or subscribe on **CollectionChanged** event **Children** property in **ElementTreeNodeVisual** class  and add new elements to your inner collection in a real time, for instance.

Comment: Thank you! This is still a quite elegant solution compared to copy-pasting the same method in the child class. Too bad that the WPF control requires us to do such hacks.